# Stripe presentPaymentSheet() method does not dismiss itself and return any kind of response React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, stripe-payments

Hello I am trying to integrate stripe payment method in react native app everything work fine except for last step in which presentPaymentSheet has to dismiss and payment should be successfull in stripe account but it says incomplete in stripe account.

[image: Stripe account payment incomplete]

**Client Side Code**

```
const { initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet } = useStripe();

const { paymentIntent, ephemeralKey, customer } =
  await fetchPaymentSheetParams();
const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
  customerId: customer,
  customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
  paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,

});
if (!error) {
  setPaymentSheetEnabled(true);
}

const openPaymentSheet = async () => {

if (!clientSecret) {
  return;
}
setLoading(true);
const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet();
console.log({error});
}
```

**Server Side Code**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);
console.log(stripe);
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.paymentSheet = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
const db = admin.firestore();
const uid = db.collection("place_order").doc("id");
const id = await uid.get();
const cityRef = db.collection("orders").doc(id.data().id);
const doc = await cityRef.get();
const price = doc.data().order;
const code = db.collection("settings").doc("currency");
const currencyCode = await code.get();
const cCode = currencyCode.data().code;
const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  {customer: customer.id},
  {apiVersion: "2022-08-01"},
);
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
amount: price[price.length - 1].order_data[0].price * 100,
currency: cCode,
customer: customer.id,
automatic_payment_methods: {
  enabled: true,
},
});
res.json({
paymentIntent: paymentIntent,
ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
customer: customer.id,
});
```

});

Comment: So you're not getting any errors at all? Are you seeing any other logs? Anything unusual from your stripe request logs? Also just to confirm - you are seeing the Payment Sheet open and you're completing payment, correct?

Comment: I get log when i cancel payment sheet only. When i submit payment it gets shown on stripe account and a little loader on button but after that nothing happens...

Comment: You mention a little loader on the button, but haven't gone into detail about the exact behavior - does it just continue to load and never dismiss the sheet? Also what version of the React Native and the Stripe library are you using? It looks like they made a recent fix in 0.18.1 of the stripe library (see https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0181---2022-08-19) that sounds similar to your issue.

Comment: @SherazHussain, Have you found any solution? 

I'm using this version of stripe  "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.29.0",